# Are we required to accept payments through inapp purchase in app?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

When accepting payments in an app, do we have to use inapp purchasing, can we use Stripe for example? I ask because it takes way too long for apple to pay us when people buy. Also, does anyone know of a good open source library that I can use to accept payments with apple pay, credit card, etc?
Im selling subscriptions to view book summaries.

Comment: What can be purchased in/with your application? Digital Items within your App or physical Goods?

Comment: If you're selling "outside" goods (e.g., something like a subscription for chocolate-of-the-month or whatever), then you can't use IAP.  If you're selling digital goods for use within the app, you must use IAP.  Apple has the final say in what constitutes inside or outside goods.

Answer (score 1):

It really depend's what you are selling.

Checkout Apple's Human Interface Guidelines

*It’s important for app developers to understand the difference between in-app purchase and Apple Pay. Use in-app purchase to sell virtual goods in your app, such as premium content for your app and subscriptions for digital content. Use Apple Pay in your app to sell physical goods like groceries, clothing, and appliances; for services such as club memberships, hotel reservations, and event tickets; and for donations.*

As for a library, [Revenuecat](https://www.revenuecat.com/integrations/) is brilliant, but then again, it depends on what you are selling and if it works for your needs. They have a [Stripe](https://www.stripe.com) integration.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering about services and wasn't getting a lot with my search query. Thank you!